# How can get CheckBox Array length in java script

Tags: javascript

in my jsp form i have one checkbox Array in my form(jsp and struts).i want to know the length of checkbox Array in java script. ex: `<input:checkbox property="chkbox[]"/>` .  in javascript  i am calling `document.form[0].chkbox[].value.length` but it showing javaScript error null or undefined .

Answer (score 3):

```
    var checkbox = document.getElementsByName('a_checkbox')
    var ln = checkbox.length
```

line 1 get all the active checked boxes
line 2 in the length of that array

Comment: i tried above code it notworking. i defined check box array like <td><input type="checkbox" name="<%=chkViaPlace%>" value="<%=chkViaPlace%>"/></td>

Comment: what i did was <label><input type="checkbox" name="add_to_email" value="{{property.id}}" />Add to email?</label> which is a check-box on my template, then in the javascript i did     $('.email-button').click(function(){
        var check = document.getElementsByName('add_to_email')
        var len = check.length
});

Comment: the above code working but length always showing "0"(zero), after selecting one than one checkbox also.

Answer (score 1):

if this the html

```
<form name='form1' >
<input type=checkbox name='cbox' />
<input type=checkbox name='cbox' />
<input type=checkbox name='cbox' />
<input type=checkbox name='cbox' />
<input type=checkbox name='cbox' />
<input type=checkbox name='cbox' />
<input type=checkbox name='cbox' />
</form>
```

javascript for that length would be

`alert(document.form1.cbox.length);`

or you can also use.

`document.getElementsByName('cbox').length`

Comment: i tried above code , still i getting undefined error. i defined checkbox array like this <td><input type="checkbox" name="<%=chkViaPlace%>" value="<%=chkViaPlace%>"/></td>

Comment: see in your bowser what html is being built up.Post your html here.

Comment: <td><input type="checkbox" name="<%=chkViaPlace%>" value="<%=chkViaPlace%>"/></td> . is the checbox code i written in form. i tired with document.getElementsByName('chkViaPlace').length but it showing result "0" . actually i checked two check box values before calling the length.

Comment: <%=chkViaPlace%> chkViaPlace is a jsp variable what is it resolving to .Please check that see view source in your code. And see what html do you get.

Comment: hi this is the source <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkViaPlace[0]" value="chkViaPlace[0]"/></td>

Comment: this is the error in mozilla web console [17:47:28.172] document.getElementsByNames is not a function

Comment: sorry document.getElementsByName('chkViaPlace').length  working but it always showing length = "0"(zero) if checked more than one check boxes

Comment: instead of chkViaPlace write chkViaPlace[0] and then try.

Comment: hi sushil , just now i tired like that also now length result is "1" but 3 chkboxes are selected. i observed one thing before checking , i seen source of that element is chkViaPlace[0] . after selecting the check boxes also i saw source of that element is same. is any thing wrong?

Comment: I think u need to get lot of basics right first before solving this.